# It is possible to switch from NOSQL provider to another?

Tags: firebase, server, nosql

Sorry for the newbie question. I want to useCloudFirestore from firebase (Google) to handle the data such as users, images, passwords etc.

My question is, once I choose this services is posible in a future to migrate to another service such as MongoDb, does the users los their password or something?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is yours, you can migrate it to wherever you like. You will be able to export any data stored on firebase and re-import it anywhere.

If you are talking specifically to firebase auth and the users login information, you can also import/export that data, check if this document covers your concerns: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth

Comment: Thank you very much, Estevao